# How to play the video smoothly on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html5-video

When I'm using video element in a webpage, the video data source is from another website. If the network is well, it will fetch video data from that website and If you want to let the video play smoothly, the buffering data `video.buffered.end(0)-video.buffered.start(0)` of the video must be longer than the currentTime `video.currentTime` , of the video.and I want to know wheather there exist such a numberbuffering data long minus video's currentTime` that can make the video play smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally Speaking, the number is not exits, but you can assume an number such as 3, 5 etc,when the time of the buffering minus the currenttime of the video is larger than 3 or 5, the video will play smoothly, otherwise, the video will be in buffering stage, and it will jank, play not smoothly.the code is as bellow:

```
if(window.video.buffered.length !== 0){
 // assume the user have not use the progress bar to control the play progress of the video, so there is only an element in buffered array(object)
   var bufferTime = window.video.buffered.end(0) - window.video.buffered.start(0);
   var currentTime = window.video.currentTime;
// another number is OK;
   if(bufferTime - currentTime < 2){
       video.dispatchEvent(bufferingEvent);
  // write capture event function;
  }
```

}